# GA4 parameters guide doesn't specify VAT inc or ex in value

Tags: documentation, google-analytics-4, tax

Re:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ga4/reference/events?client_type=gtag#begin_checkout

In sections such as "begin_checkout", the documentation on the "value" parameter doesn't specify whether the value amount is inclusive or exclusive of VAT.

Can you please clarify in the documentation if this value should or should not include VAT, if it is applicable in the cart items?

Answer (score 0):

I would say this is personal preference on whether you pull in the tax total or just the value of the cart.

I am sure if you wanted to know both parameters, you could just create a separate parameter for the VAT and pass it along with the other data.